# Can you build static websites with React (Gatsby, Next) in the same way you would with jQuery, with animations and carousels?

Tags: jquery, reactjs, gatsby, next.js

I am new to a company in which websites are built with jQuery and plugins such as WoW and Owl Carousel. However, I would like to try and work with React for the same purpose. Is it possible? What would I not be able to build?

I have tried reddit or google with this specificity but no luck. If this is a dumb question, I'll be happy to be given a link to read about this.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery is still Javascript, so you should be able to do the same with React, though that doesn't mean that Jquery libraries work with React out of the box. 
There are Carousel Components on Github you can use for similar results.